# Golang, first argument to append must be slice; have struct

Tags: go

brand new to go here and trying to set up a simple rest server to get the basics down of go. I have my routes configured and am now trying to set up some basic POST/GET calls with just storing some items in memory. I am trying to set up a struct and just push a payload into memory and fetch for example. I am not sure how to fix this error, but here is what I have so far.

The activity setup (activity.go):

```
package main

type Activity struct {
    activityCgid      string     `json:"activityCgid"`
    title             string     `json:"title"`
    description       string     `json:"description"`
    availableDate     int        `json:"availableDate"`
    dueDate           int        `json:"dueDate"`
    navigationTypes   []string   `json:"navigationTypes"`
    containerCgi      string     `json:"containerCgi"`
    position          int        `json:"position"`
}

type Activities []Activity
```

And then in my repo.go, I just have this :

```
func RepoCreateActivity(t Activity) Activity {
    activities = append(activities, t)
    return t
}
```

and above it, I have :

```
 var activities Activity
```

To which go is pointing to and saying `first argument to append must be slice; have struct` (and the struct following). Would appreciate any advice as I have just begun learning go. Thank you for reading!

Comment: Where is the activities variable in the function RepoCreateActivity defined?

Comment: Two things: first you have a typo: `Activities` instead of `activities`. Second: do not forget to export the json struct fields.

Comment: @BenjaminKadish activities is in the top of the repo.go (package level I think?) and that function is inside that same file, I edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 var activities Activity
```

that should be

```
 var activities Activities
```